# How erase part of UIImage with an other UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics, erase

I posted that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526336/how-erase-part-of-uiimage) and I have not yet found a solution.
I was wondering if there is a way to use an `UIImage` to delete a part of an other `UIImage`
[image]

I would use an `UIImage` to 'mask' this ugly black background to let a transparency color.
Maybe with `CGContextAddPath` but I don't know how to use it...

Regards,
KL94

Comment: There a few approaches and it would help to know if you want to mask a solid color like a "green screen" technique or are you going to be masking background images. Also, will you be masking across the entire image or just in a certain clipping path?

Comment: I want to mask the background image. The image is representative of what I need. I'm looking for a way to erase only the black part of the entire image in order to replace it (the black area) by a transparency. I suppose I have to use an other image to do that but I'm maybe in a wrong way...

Comment: I found this 
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978382/how-to-erase-part-of-an-image-as-the-user-touches-it?rq=1
Hope it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

```
- (UIImage*)eraseImage:(UIImage*)img1 WithImage:(UIImage*)img2
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img1.size);
    [img1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, img1.size.width, img1.size.height)];
    [img2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, img2.size.width, img2.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn alpha:1.0];
    UIImage* result_img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result_img;
}
```

But you better save image as transparent.(Like PNG)

Comment: to fully replace the area use `kCGBlendModeCopy`